# Can we use pooled ols on dynamic panel without individual fixed effect (but with group fixed effects) and no serial correlation in error

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, method-of-moments, dynamic-regression

Is it correct that dynamic panel without individual fixed effect (but with group fixed effects), no serial correlation in error  can be estimated consistently through pooled ols?

For example, suppose we have
$$
y_{it} = \rho y_{it-1} + \beta x_{it}+v_g+\epsilon_{it}
$$
where $E(x_{it}\epsilon_{it})=0$ and $E(y_{it-1}\epsilon_{it})=0$.

Do we need to use Arellano and Bond's GMM method in the above case?

Comment: Is $y_{it}$ on the right-hand side a lag of your outcome?

Comment: @ThomasBilach It's a typo. I have corrected it.